# Ideal nonthin subsets

Tags: filters

Let $\mathscr{I}$ be an ideal on the positive integer $\mathbb{N}$, that is, a collection of subsets closed under taking finite unions and subsets of its elements. In addition, we assume that $\mathscr{I}$ contain all finite sets and it is different from the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.

> **Question**. Fix two sets $I,J\notin \mathscr{I}$ where the canonical enumeration of $I$ is $(i_1,i_2,\ldots)$. Is it true that
>   $
> \{i_j: j \in J\} \notin \mathscr{I}\,\,?
> $

Comment: Why do you need a real-valued sequence here ?

Comment: @Max You're right, we do not need sequences at all, I edited the question. Even if the answer is positive for $\mathscr{I}$ equal to the ideal generated by the asymptotic density, I expted the answer is negative in general..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be the ideal generated by finite sets and the set of odd prime numbers $\mathcal{P}$. We let $(p_n)$ denote the sequence of odd prime numbers ($p_0= 3$)

Then let $I$ be a set that contains $\mathcal{P}$ and such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $I$ contains precisely one element between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$, and such that $3= min I$.

Then $I \notin \mathcal{I}$. Moreover, if you enumerate $I$, you get $I= \{ p_0, x_0, p_1, x_1, p_2, ... \}$. Putting $J= 2\Bbb{N}$ you get that $J\notin \mathcal{I}$.

Then, using your notations $\{i_j, j \in J\} = \{i_{2n}, n\in \Bbb{N}\} = \{p_0, p_1, ... \}= \mathcal{P}$ and therefore it is in $\mathcal{I}$.

Of course there are many examples that work like this, and obviously many examples where it isn't in $\mathcal{I}$

Comment: Isn't this the same ideal as the one generated by the prime numbers? Since $\{2\}$ is certainly a finite set...

Comment: @Asaf : indeed, but I simply needed the notation $\mathcal{P}$ to describe $I$ (there is no integer strictly between $2$ and $3$).

Comment: @Max It works, perfect! :)